# PHP/MariaDB On Duplicate Key Update with nested JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb, webhooks

So this one is fun.  I'm integrating a 3rd party POS into my custom inventory management software I made for this client some time ago.
My system is a basic PHP/HTML/JS background.
I have webhooks from the 3rd party system sending my site JSON information about product info and stock details.
The issue I have is that when we update a product in the 3rd party system, I need to set up my prepared INSERT Statement to UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY.  The KEY that needs to be checked is the 3rd column in the database, and is the only Unique Key in the table.
The Primary Key is another ID, not provided by the 3rd party system.
I can't seem to "build" this ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE function correctly for the life of me.

Here's some code to make sense of things:
Product Information comes through in hook.php which has the following:

```
HOOK.php
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$request3 = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
req_dump1 = print_r( $request3, true ); 
fp = file_put_contents( 'req.json', $req_dump1 ); 
?>
```

This gives me the following JSON:

```
{
  "Id": 8919892,
  "Name": "Final",
  "Description": "Final",
  "CostPrice": 0.95000,
  "SalePrice": 756.00000,
  "CategoryId": 278333,
  "Barcode": "2020202020",
   "BrandId": 151102,
  "SupplierId": 44815,
  "OrderCode": "LKJ-8376594",
   "ProductType": 0,
  "TareWeight": null,
  "ArticleCode": "44-jhaqerkhu",
   "Supplier": {
    "Id": 44815,
    "Name": "House",
    "Description": "House",
   },
  }
```

Then the rest of the stock information comes from Stock Detail (why they[3rd party] have it separated IDK, I didn't build it) which hits hook4.php:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');

$request1=str_replace('[', '', $request);

$request2=str_replace(']', '', $request1);

$req_dump = print_r( $request2, true );

$fp = file_put_contents( 'req4.json', $req_dump );


include('ai.php');
?>
```

This gives me the following JSON

```
REQ4.json
{
  "Id": 2553369,
  "ProductId": 8919892,
  "MinStock": 300,
    "ProductStockBatches": {
    "Id": 3656516,
    "StockId": 2553369,
    "CreatedDate": "2021-08-08T03:41:24.153",
    "CurrentStock": 225,
    "CurrentVolume": 0,
    "CostPrice": 0.95000,
      }
}
```

So all of that is fine and dandy, the issue is in ai.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "terblah";
$password = "blah";
$dbname = "blah";
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO blah (name, prod_id, cost, price, brand, vendor_sku, upc, code, on_hand, par,  upd_date) VALUES (:name, :prod_id, :cost, :price, :brand, :vendor_sku, :upc, :code, :currentstock, :parstock,  :upd_date) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod_id = :prod_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':prod_id', $prod_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cost', $cost);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $price);
    $stmt->bindParam(':brand', $brand);
    $stmt->bindParam(':vendor_sku', $ven_sku);
    $stmt->bindParam(':upc', $upc);
    $stmt->bindParam(':code', $code);
    $stmt->bindParam(':currentstock', $on_hand);
    $stmt->bindParam(':parstock', $par);
    $stmt->bindParam(':upd_date', $upd);
    $js = file_get_contents('req.json');
    $js0 = file_get_contents('req4.json');
    $dt = json_decode($js, true);
    $dt0 = json_decode($js0, true);
    $name = $dt['Name'];
    $prod_id = $dt0['ProductId'];
    $cost = $dt['CostPrice'];
    $price = $dt['SalePrice'];
    $brand = $dt['Supplier']['Name'];
    $ven_sku = $dt['OrderCode'];
    $code = $dt['ArticleCode'];
    $upc = $dt['Barcode'];
    $on_hand = $dt0['ProductStockBatches']['CurrentStock'];
    $par = $dt0['MinStock'];
    $upd = $dt0['ProductStockBatches']['CreatedDate'];
       
    $stmt->execute();
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();

}
$conn = null;
?>
```

The issue is the `prod_id = :prod_id`.
I can't define it as `$prod_id`, i get the following that way:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

Leaving it as is tells me:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'prod_id' cannot be null
```

Which I understand is because I'm asking it to search for a variable that isn't defined yet.  When i move the definitions I get binding errors because the statement to be prepared isn't called yet, but I need the defined key first....so I'm wondering if I'm just missing a trick somewhere.

I haven't tried it yet, but I had the thought of calling req4.json 2x in the ai.php, first simply just to define the variable to be searched in the duplicate key situation.  But how do I call a '$' variable in the middle of a SQL statement?
I know how to call a defined variable, but how do I pull that definition from JSON and then use it as a variable in the SQL statement?

Can I

```
$ts = file_get_contents('req4.json');
$js1 = json_decode($ts, true);
$var = $js1['ProductId'];
```

then in my ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (prod_id = ?)
```

and at the end

```
$stmt->execute($var);
```

I tried that and I got

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters
```

Which leaves me here.
Am I even asking this question correctly?
Can somebody who has a brain that isn't currently not working please give me an hand?

Comment: Whereas I know I need to define binding "s" to '?" but where and how do I do that?
I'm lost.

Comment: `req4.json` is not valid JSON. The comma between `0.95000` and `}` is not allowed.

Comment: Use `UPDATE prod_id = VALUES(prod_id)`.

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($prod_id);`? It seems like this variable is null.

Comment: Which column is the unique column?

Comment: The unique column is prod_id, the comma might be leftover from me removing company propietary info from the data. The necessary information is provided, if you remove the comma it can parse.

Comment: $prod_id is defined as $prod_id=$dt0['ProductId'] which in this data set is line 4 from REQ4.json "Product Id: 8919892".
That number changes obviously per the update detail information sent over that recreated in req4 with each event trigger.

Comment: If `prod_id` is the unique column, why are you trying to update it? You'll just be updating it to itself.

Comment: When you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, you update all or some of the other columns, not the key that's duplicated.

Comment: But the errors you're getting imply that `$prod_id` is null, not a number like `8919892`. Are you sure the file has the `ProductId:` line?

Comment: YES when I var_dump $prod_id I get int(8920898) but for some reason it responds like its null.

Comment: However, I did change to Values(prod_id) so I need to triple check if that works, hold on just a sec

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to do that in the first place.

Comment: If you just want to skip the duplicate, use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: I changed it to VALUES(prod_id) and that didn't update on insert, the table data is unchanged. 
What I need to happen is when a new event triggers ai.php, if prod_id already exists, update table data instead of inserting a new row.
I was attempting to do this without having to write a full if isset function and rewrite a new UPDATE sql query.

Comment: As I said above, you should be updating all the OTHER columns, not `prod_id`. `name = VALUES(name), cost = VALUES(cost), ...`

Comment: Which for all intents SHOULD be possible with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but I think because of the way i need to define said KEY, it's fruitless without rewriting the whole API php.

Comment: I'm confused by that statement, I want to only update all the other columns, but only update those columns by the prod_id key.  How do I tell it to search for prod_id key and if exists then update that row and only that row, otherwise create a new row, by using IGNORE?
Is that what you are saying?  With ignore I thought it ignores anything and everything that might be the same and if two rows have the same amount of stock, won't it just update that row instead of going by the prod_id key?
Am I missing something in your statement?

Comment: That's what ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does. When it detects a duplicate key, it updates just that row as specified, instead of trying to create a new row.

Comment: RIGHT, but as we have already discussed, ON DUPLICATE KEY for some reason read the defined key as null instead on the actual key that gets printed with var_dump which doesn't make sense, and we are right back where we started LOL.

Comment: WAIT.  You are saying instead of UPDATE (prod_id etc, then UPDATE (everything else_else, else, else, etc) ? @ Barmar please don't tell me I'm that dumb and I just argued with you about that.

Comment: I guess I'll have to keep quiet....

Comment: @Barmar you've got to be kidding me.  I wrote the stupid DUPLICATE function backwards?   OH.  I have misunderstood this command for years

Comment: `INSERT INTO invent (name, prod_id, cost, price, brand, vendor_sku, upc, on_hand, par,  upd_date) VALUES (:name, :prod_id, :cost, :price, :brand, :vendor_sku, :upc, :currentstock, :parstock,  :upd_date) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (name = VALUES(name), 
        cost = VALUES(cost), 
        price = VALUES(price), 
        brand = VALUES(brand), 
        vendor_sku = VALUES(vendor_sku), 
        upc = VALUES(upc), 
        purple_haze_code = VALUES(purple_haze_code), 
        on_hand = VALUES(on_hand),
        par = VALUES(par),
        upd_date = VALUES(upd_date)`

Comment: This returns SYNTAX errors, whereas I'm using MariaDB and backticks around each `('name' = VALUES('name'), etc)` didn't work either same SYNTAX error.  Any ideas on the format of that? Should I leave out VALUES?

Comment: No quotes around the column names.

Comment: No parentheses either. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), cost = VALUES(cost), price = VALUES(price), ...`

Comment: Well.  That updated the stock information but replaced literally everything else with NULL.

Comment: I apparently don't have the rep to have a chat, is there another way we can chat?.  I don't mind continuing here I just dont want either of us to get yelled at by mods for over commenting.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would do that. If the values are correct for inserting, it should use the same values when updating.

Comment: HAHA.  Apparently req.json got wiped at some point, it was empty.  It works perfectly.  Can you please put your fix in an answer so I can check it and upvote it and give you the props.  Thank you Barmar.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign to all the *other* columns in `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The `prod_id` column is the one that the duplication is checked from.

You can use `VALUES(colname)` to get the value that would have been inserted.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO blah (name, prod_id, cost, price, brand, vendor_sku, upc, code, on_hand, par,  upd_date) 
        VALUES (:name, :prod_id, :cost, :price, :brand, :vendor_sku, :upc, :code, :currentstock, :parstock,  :upd_date) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        name = VALUES(name), cost = VALUES(cost), price = VALUES(price), brand = VALUES(brand), vendor = VALUES(vendor)_sku = VALUES(sku), upc = VALUES(upc), code = VALUES(code), on = VALUES(on)_hand = VALUES(hand), par = VALUES(par),  upd = VALUES(upd)_date = VALUES(date)");
```